# ssrs footer dynamic textbox

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, footer

In the `footer` of my report, It contains `textbox 1` and `textbox2`.

I want to textbox 1 be *hidden both on the page 1 and 2*. But, I only know how to hide it on the page 1. 
I am using expression `=IIf(cstr(Globals!PageNumber)="1", True, False)`in the visibility .

Do anyone know how to hide the textbox 1 for page 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same **Expression** but just add the extra logic for the second page.

```
=IIf(cstr(Globals!PageNumber) = "1" OR cstr(Globals!PageNumber) = "2", True, False)
```

You don't really need to convert to a String with the **CSTR** function nor use the quotes around the number:

```
=IIf(Globals!PageNumber = 1 OR Globals!PageNumber = 2, True, False)
```